# Why the output of select nullif(0,'') is NULL (0 is expected)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why the output of `select nullif(0,'')` is NULL? (0 is expected).

How come 0 is equal to ''?

When I use select nullif(convert(varchar,0),'') it actually returns the expected 0.

`NULLIF` official page says the function compares two scalar expressions. Is 0 not scalar? Please tell me what am I missing in my understanding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Integers are higher up in the [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx), so the varchar is converted to an int. An empty string converted to an int is `0`, and from there it's pretty obvious (`0 == 0`).

`0 == 0`, thus `NULLIF(0, 0) => NULL` (since `NULLIF(a, b)` returns `NULL` iff `a == b`)

---

When you do `nullif(convert(varchar,0),'')`, you're just doing `NULLIF('0', '')`. Obviously a string containing only 0 and an empty string are not equal, thus you get `0`.

---

A more in-depth explanation is that two different types cannot actually be compared. You can't compare a string an integer, or a string and a float, or an integer and a float, or, so on. This means that to do comparisons of different types, there must be some kind of implicit casting rule. In this case, it just so happens that if you compare a string (well, technically a varchar) and an int, the varchar is converted to an int implicitly. This is a lot easier to see if you consider the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, '');

IF '' = 0 SELECT 'Equal' ELSE SELECT 'Not equal';
```

As you'll see, the conversion yields an integer valued 0. Furthermore, this leads to the comparison between the two evaluating to true.

Comment: Thank you, Corbin, for explanation! It may be an off-side question, but why can't you compare two different data types, as all the data consists of symbols and if the sequence of symbols is the same then two items are the same and if not - then they are different. Or is it too human-skewed way of thinking?

Comment: In which sql version does 'SELECT '' = 0' return true ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk 2008 and 2012 for sure. Not sure about the others off the top of my head.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Ah, yeah. Used to MySQL these days. Just put it in an if or case to get the same effect of just checking how it evaluates. I'm surprised MS SQL won't select an expression of literals :/.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the `nullif` function is casting both values either to type `bit` or `int`, as implied by the first value?

If so, they would both evaluate to a value of 0, thus the `nullif` would return `null` as you are seeing.

This would explain why converting to `varchar` solves the problem.

Comment: It converts them to int.

Comment: Select CAST('' as int)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I thought it was a cast but I didn't know that empty string would result in integer 0.

Comment: converting 0 into varchar gives us a string containing Zero like '0' in this case it will return the 1st expression which is 0, this makes total sense but the question is when we have 0 int 1st expression and an empty string second expression why it returns NULL , as INT 0 is not equal to string '0'